# JUnit - Test Max Number of Objects Created

Tags: java, junit, assert

I have a very small class, **BuildThreeObjects**, which creates a maximum of 3 Objects using a private int variable, **numObjects**, to store the count. If the count is < 3, a new Object is returned else `null` is returned.

Could anyone guide me on how to test if a maximum of 3 Objects are created using JUnit. Looking at the API didn't help much. I assumed `assertNotNull` or `assertNull` would be used but I can't think how to.

---

*// Code for BuildThreeObjects class*

```
public class BuildThreeObjects {
    private int numObjects = 0;

    public Object buildObject() {
        if (numObjects<3) {
                numObjects++;
            return new Object();
        }
        else return null;
    }
}
```

*// Code within the JUnit class; all unnecessary code omitted*

```
private BuildThreeObjects bto;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    bto = new BuildThreeObjects();
}

@Test
public void testBuild() {
    assertNotNull(bto.buildObject());
}

// assertNotNull passes and assertNull fails as it only checks the first object creation
```

Comment: could you show us some of your code? It seems to me like it is best to keep track of the amount of objects in some static variable.

Comment: I was thinking a for-loop somehow but after looking around all I can find is use of params or repeat, both of which require more coding that I think necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
class BuildThreeObjects{
    int count = 0;
    public Object buildObject(){
        if(count >= 3){
            return null;
        } else {
            count++;
            return new Object();
        }
    }
}

private BuildThreeObjects bto;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    bto = new BuildThreeObjects();
}

@Test
public void testBuild() {
    assertNotNull(bto.buildObject());
    System.out.println(bto.count);
    assertNotNull(bto.buildObject());
    System.out.println(bto.count);
    assertNotNull(bto.buildObject());
    System.out.println(bto.count);
    assertNull(bto.buildObject());
    System.out.println(bto.count);
}
```

// with for loop

```
for(int i=0; i < 100; i++){
        if(i < 3){
            assertNotNull(bto.buildObject());
            System.out.println(bto.count);
        } else {
             assertNull(bto.buildObject());
               System.out.println(bto.count);
        }
    }
```

Comment: why do you think making count private would change anything? you're using it only inside of the class, so you have access to 'count' anyway

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I deleted my comment as it was silly. This works fine, thank you. I have no idea why I couldn't get this now!

Comment: As a side, had there been more than 3 objects, say 100, how would I go about doing that without writing 100 lines of code?

Comment: @ConnorMcGuile If you have some large number, it would be better to inject the "max objects to create" parameter in the class. In this case, for test purposes you could inject a small number and do a simple test, for application usage you inject a number which is required in your app. Otherwise, your unit test suddenly became bloated and it is more as performance test.

Answer (score 1):

Just literally do it:

```
assertNotNull(createObject());

assertNotNull(createObject());

assertNotNull(createObject());

assertNull(createObject());
```

you could use for-loop also if it could be more expressive.